# Assign link to HTML button on GAS

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

**UPDATE:** Thank you everyone for your help, especially ale13. I have updated the question with the final code that worked for me.

I am trying to create a HTML button that pops up within my Google Sheets and on click it should trigger the download of the sheet. I created the button and everything else runs perfectly. When I manually get the link generated and click on it, the file downloads. However, when I click on the button, nothing happens.

**This is the code to launch the HTML.**

```
function downloadPopup(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Button');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Download Lists as CSV');
}
```

**Setting and getting the property**

```
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('urlD', downloadURL);
```

```
function urlHTML(){
  return PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('urlD');
}
```

**This is the HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_center">
  <style>
.
.
.
</style>
  </head>
  <script>
    var downloadURL = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('urlD');
    function downloadFile(downloadURL){
      window.open(downloadURL);
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <div id="buttonlink"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(downloadFile).urlHTML()" class="button">Download CSV</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try `<input type="button"  onclick="downloadFile();" />Download CSV` and add Logger.log() to gs.

Comment: Cooper is correct

Comment: Thanks guys, however I need to style the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you modify the code as following:

**Code.gs**

```js
function downloadPopup(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Button');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Download Lists as CSV');
}

function urlHTML(){
  return downloadURL;
}
```

**Button.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_center">
  <style>
</style>
  </head>
  <script>
    function downloadFile(downloadURL){
      window.open(downloadURL, '_self');
    }
  </script>
  <body>
   <div id="buttonLink"></div>
   <button type="button" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(downloadFile).urlHTML()">Preview The Document</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unless you really need two distinct functions for returning URL, I would suggest you to use just one which will return the URL directly when called. As a side note, it is important to bear in mind that Apps Script's global variables are different in comparison to the ones in other programming languages - each new invocation of the functions will end up returning a new context to the script without memory of earlier executions unless these were kept. For storing a global variable correctly, I suggest you take a look at [this class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties).

As for the HTML part, when the button is being clicked, the `withSuccessHandler(downloadFile)` allows you to specify a client-side callback function to run when the `urlHTML()` server function responds. In order to open the link in a new window, the `window.open` has been used.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Client-to-Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

Comment: Thank you ale13! It worked! However, it is taking many seconds to open the other page and download the file. When I did it with the hyperlink, it was super quick. I also tried to use the property service but it didn't work once I did. I created a property  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('urlD', downloadURL);, then on the HTML I tried to call it. It didn't work, so I created a var in the HTML and used it in the downloadFIle function. That didn't work either. Do you have any tips to make the download start quickly and to work with the property? Thank you!

Comment: You will have to set the property using `setProperty` and later retrieve it using `getProperty` - afterwards, instead of returning the `downloadURL` variable, you will return the property you just retrieved :) As for the slowness downloading of the file, this might be caused by something on your side, as I was able to start the download quick.

Comment: Thank you so much @ale13! It is working perfectly now! I got a bit confused with the `withSuccessHandler(downloadFile).urlHTML()` and how to insert the property into the `downloadFile()` function. I don't understand why we add `.urlHTML()` after the `withSuccessHandler` because it looks like it's doing nothing. The `downloadFile()` function is doing everything. Would you know a function to start the download without opening another tab?

Comment: You can use the `'_self'` attribute with `window.open` - `window.open(downloadURL,'_self')`. This should trigger the download instantly without opening a new tab.

Comment: Thank you ale13! That worked perfectly and it works exactly the way I needed it to work! You're so good! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" value="Download CSV" onclick="downloadFile()" />
```

Sample code from a project showing how to style buttons and such

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  <!-- Add CSS code to format the sidebar from google stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 20px;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="block">
    <input type="button" value="Get Sheet Size" onclick="getSheetSize()" />
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <div id="results"></div>  
  </div>
 <script>
 function getSheetSize() {
  //google.script.run.auditSheet();
  //google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayResults).auditSheet();
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayResults).auditAllSheets();

 }

 function displayResults(results) {
  // display results in sidebar
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = results;
}

 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you John, but I need to style the button.

Comment: Use DIVs and Styles, I will post code from one of my projects